# jsf *.xhtml mapping not working, redirected to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I have a simple jsf 1.2 project (richfaces 3.3 implementation) where I have set the servlet mapping to `*.xhtml`. I also have a simple bean and a simple page to display the data.

I try to run the project, but, although I request `mypage.xhtml`, I am somehow redirected and I get the following error:

```
The requested resource (/rich_test/mypage.jsp) is not available.
```

Where does error come from?

Is there any further setting I need to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JSF 1.x, the default view technology is JSP. Facelets (XHTML) only became default in JSF 2.x. If you want to use Facelets in JSF 1.x, you basically need to set the default suffix to `.xhtml` instead of `.jsp` (after having installed the Facelets JAR file and registered the Facelets view handler).

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, on JSF 1.x, this way the `FacesServlet` will run in an infinite loop because everytime when it needs to resolve the XHTML file, it would invoke itself again. This issue does not occur on JSF 2.x anymore. For JSF 1.x, your best bet is to use the URL pattern of `*.jsf` instead.

Comment: Got a blank page and `faces-config="2.0"` in faces-config.xml... why? xhtml is default in 2.0 right?

Comment: @texas: press 'Ask Question' button if you have a question.